# class toggle on click element only

Tags: angularjs

I want active class only on the a tag that i click on, rest should show 'inactive class':

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $log){
       $scope.activeact=false;
       $scope.makeactive=function(){

       $scope.activeact=true;
    }
});


<ul>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="makeactive()" ng-class="activeact ? 'active' : 'inactive'">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="makeactive()" ng-class="activeact ? 'active' : 'inactive'">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="makeactive()" ng-class="activeact ? 'active' : 'inactive'">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

pls help

Comment: Is number of list elements, i.e, number of <li> tags fixed?

Comment: it is menu? routing between pages?

Comment: yes, they are fixed, you can give example to ng-repeat later, after answer for fixed li's

Comment: there is no routing

Answer (score 2):

Considering the number of list elements are fixed and small for a easy solution;

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $log){

       $scope.makeactive=function(num){
            $scope['li'+num]=true;
       }
});
```

And the HTML is:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" ng-click="makeactive(1)" ng-class="li1 ? 'active' : 'inactive'">one</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" ng-click="makeactive(2)" ng-class="li2 ? 'active' : 'inactive'">Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" ng-click="makeactive(3)" ng-class="li3 ? 'active' : 'inactive'">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Obviously it is not a generalised solution, but for small elements this is an easier one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do! Make use of `ng-repeat` using following array:

```
$scope.numbers = ["one", "two", "three"];
```

Now, your `ng-repeat` on `<li>` would look like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="num in numbers">
  <a href="#" ng-click="makeactive($index)" 
     ng-class="activeact{{$index}} ? 'active' : 'inactive'"
     ng-bind="num">
  </a>
</li>
```

Now, on `click` of your links, `active`/`inactive` will toggle.

Here's the working code snippet!

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $log) {
    $scope.activeact = false;
    $scope.numbers = ["one","two","three"]
    $scope.makeactive = function(index) {
      $scope["activeact"+index] = !Boolean($scope["activeact"+index]);
    }
  });
```

```css
.active {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="num in numbers"><a href="#" ng-click="makeactive($index)" ng-class="activeact{{$index}} ? 'active' : 'inactive'">{{num}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use different code like this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" ng-click="makeactive(1)" ng-class="selectedindex==1 ? 'active' : 'inactive'">one</a></li>
<li><a href="#" ng-click="makeactive(2)" ng-class="selectedindex==2 ? 'active' : 'inactive'">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#" ng-click="makeactive(3)" ng-class="selectedindex==3 ? 'active' : 'inactive'">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

In controller

```
$scope.makeactive=function(index){    
  $scope.selectedindex=index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ui-router :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="home">home</a></li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="about">about</a</li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

for tutorials here : [github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/) and [Scotch](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router)

examples of ui router : [exaple 1](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/) and [codepen](http://codepen.io/alexandremasy/pen/mDcEd)

you can do with ui-router the same without ng-class or ng-repeat